# Barcode4j + qr not working

Tags: java, xml, apache-fop, barcode4j

I have problems trying to generate an image with qr code via barcode4j library.
I've read the [following guide](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/2.1/fop-ext.html) but that didn't work out.
So here is my code:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>fopqr</groupId>
    <artifactId>fopqr</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>barcode4j-fop-ext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

2. Main.java

```
import org.apache.fop.apps.Fop;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory;
import org.apache.xmlgraphics.util.MimeConstants;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/user/fop.pdf")));

        try {
            Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, out);
            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(); // identity transformer
            Source src = new StreamSource(new File("/home/user/template.xsl"));
            Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
            transformer.transform(src, res);
        }
        finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

template.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10pt">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="0.4cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="2cm">
      <fo:region-body margin-bottom="2.3cm"/>
      <fo:region-after extent="2.2cm"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4" language="en">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:block>
                  <fo:instream-foreign-object>
                    <bc:barcode xmlns:bc="http://barcode4j.krysalis.org/ns" message="hello world">
                      <bc:qr/>
                    </bc:barcode>
                  </fo:instream-foreign-object>
                </fo:block>
                 </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

When I try to launch the application with

```
kirill@kirill:~/work/source/fop$ java -jar target/fopqr-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I get

```
Mar 07, 2015 10:42:02 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
WARNING: Unknown formatting object "{http://barcode4j.krysalis.org/ns}barcode" encountered (a child of fo:instream-foreign-object}. (See position 13:99)
Mar 07, 2015 10:42:02 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
WARNING: Unknown formatting object "{http://barcode4j.krysalis.org/ns}qr" encountered (a child of barcode}. (See position 14:31)
Mar 07, 2015 10:42:02 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
SEVERE: The intrinsic dimensions of an instream-foreign-object could not be determined. (See position 12:47)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**: I also want to add that I read [FAQ](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/faq.html): 4.1. The FOP extension fails. But as you can see I added all required libraries to my pom.xml file.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why code has been formatted in such an ugly way. Please, help me to fix it.

Comment: Mark the code in the editor and then press the {}-Button above it (or indent everything by 4 spaces in another way, that's what the button does :)). Can you show us your template.xsl?

Comment: @kjosh It's already there - and the OP already used code indentation, but also using numbering messed it up.

Comment: I tried exactly as you said in the first place, but some pieces of code look bad, I don't know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. the 2.1.0 release of the barcode4j library does not contain the parts to create qr codes
2. something goes wrong when starting things from an assembled jar "with dependencies embedded"

For 2. I can only offer a workaround: add to your `pom.xml` in the build `<plugins>`:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

then you can run things with `mvn exec:java` and suddenly you should see a different error message:

```
org.krysalis.barcode4j.BarcodeException: No barcode configuration element not found
at org.krysalis.barcode4j.BarcodeUtil.createBarcodeGenerator(BarcodeUtil.java:110)
at org.krysalis.barcode4j.BarcodeUtil.createBarcodeGenerator(BarcodeUtil.java:146)
at org.krysalis.barcode4j.fop.BarcodeElement.getDimension(BarcodeElement.java:76)
```

After a while I figured out the code wanted to tell me that there is nothing to render qr-codes. (e.g. replace your `<bc:qr />` by `<bc:code39/>` and you should see the lib produces something (not a QR Code of course).

So what to do? Build from source! Have your good old `ant` and `cvs` ready!

```
cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@barcode4j.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/barcode4j co barcode4j
cd barcode4j
ant
```

That should do it, except for telling maven. Sure there is a sane way to do it, but what worked for me is:

```
cp ~/.m2/repository/net/sf/barcode4j/barcode4j/2.1/barcode4j-2.1.pom  pom.xml
vi pom.xml  # change  <version>2.1</version> to <version>2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
mvn -Dfile=build/barcode4j.jar -DpomFile=pom.xml  install:install-file
```

Now after having faked the jar into our maven repo, fix up the original `pom.xml` and update the dependencies (including a downgrade of zxing to 1.7, because the newer version is not compatible):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>barcode4j-fop-ext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

I guess it should have been better style to update the `barcode4j-fop-ext` to 2.2-SNAPSHOT too, but I leave this as an exercise for the reader. ;)

Anyway, if I run `mvn exec:java` now, I get a `fop.pdf` with a QR-Code in it. (It does not look pretty, but some fiddling with the config like adding `<bc:module-width>2mm</bc:module-width>` or whatever sure fixes it).

I have to admit that I prefer to leave it to someone else to figure out why running the same code from an assembled jar does not work.

Comment: I couldn't even imagine that creating simple image containing qr code would be such a problem :) And I myself have found another (may be a little easier) way - just generate regular qr image using zxing, get byte array, convert it to base64 string and than just use it as image url. But anyway, thanks a lot for your great answer!

Comment: There's another way of doing this: register a `ResourceResolver` with your `FopFactoryBuilder`, use `external-graphic` with src=`qr:the_code_to_use`, then parse that url in your Resolver and return the image on the fly using aByteArrayOutputStream`.